# How can I get reactstrap dropdown value to credit card component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactstrap

My english is not well, I have a credit card component. when input change get value to other component. But I want expiry month and year to get from dropdown. Here is the code, can anyone help?

codesandbox.io/s/purple-frost-lknxs

Comment: @Turtlean I think it's okey now https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-frost-lknxs

Comment: Yep, working now! Let's remove all our comments above to reduce the noise, as they're not necessary anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreditCardForm` receives an `onChange` callback from `Payment` which uses to update `name`, `number`, `expiryMonth` and `expiryYear` properties.

The problem here is that the `onChange` callback for `expiryMonth` and `expiryYear` is being triggered from `DropdownToggle's onChange` event rather than from `DropdownItem -> div -> onClick` event, which is the event that you're really interested in:

```js
<Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
  <DropdownToggle
    caret
    id="expiryMonth"
    name="expiryMonth"
    value={expiryMonth}
    onChange={(e) =>  <-- It's being called HERE
      onChange({ key: "expiryMonth", value: e.target.value })
    }
  >
    {dropDownValue}
  </DropdownToggle>
  <DropdownMenu>
    {select.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <DropdownItem
          key={`${item.id}--${index}`}
          className={classNames({
            active: dropDownValue === item.text
          })}
        >
          <div onClick={changeValue}>{item.value}</div> <-- Should be called HERE
        </DropdownItem>
      );
    })}
  </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

A simple solution is to extend both `changeValue` and `changeValue2` to call the `onChange` callback with the proper keys:

```js
function changeValue(e) {
  setDropDownValue(e.currentTarget.textContent);
  onChange({ key: "expiryMonth", e.currentTarget.textContent })
}

function changeValue2(e) {
  setDropDownValue2(e.currentTarget.textContent);
  onChange({ key: "expiryYear", e.currentTarget.textContent })
}
```

It's also a good idea to change the `initialState` in `Payment` component so `initialState` starts with the same values as the Dropdowns:

```js
const initialState = {
  name: "",
  number: "",
  expiryMonth: "01",
  expiryYear: "01",
  cvv: ""
}
```